# How to refresh the available fields in Fields Editor for a TIBTable at design time after altering the table in IBConsole?

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 10.4.1 and Interbase 2020 w/ IBConsole.

If I alter the structure of an exising table using IBConsole, when I return to Delphi, I find no way to update the structure of any corresponding TIBTable component.  If I double click the TIBTable component to open the Fields Editor and then right click to select an available fields, the available fields list is obsolete, showing only the old fields that existed before I altered the table using IBConsole.  Any new fields or field name changes I may have created/made when altering the table in IBConsole are not reflected in the list of available fields.

What is the best way to Update the list of available fields so that it corresponds with the actual current table structure?

Closing the Delphi editor and reopening it performs this update, but it seems there's got to be a better way.

Comment: Close and re-open the TIBConnection to the database, clear both the TFields and any TFieldDefs on the dataset, then recreate them?

Comment: If you mean the persistent fields those accessed by r-click 'Fields Editor' then you can use 'Add all Fields'. That should add any new ones. If you haven't added any code to those fields and changed the table layout you can select all DEL then add all..

Comment: MartynA - I guess... TIBDatabase.Connected := false...  Can be set in the Object Inspector.  I'll try that.  Thanks.

Comment: FredS - The whole problem I'm asking about is how to update the list of persistant fields so that it is correct instead of obsolete.  So no, r-click on the Fields Editor displays the incorrect list of fields.  Question is, how do I update that list at design time?